# How to call each item in array by name or index?

Tags: php

```
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{
    $firstRow = array_column($data, $i);
     foreach($firstRow as $k=>$v)
     {
        echo $k;//key
        echo"---";
        echo  $v;//value
        echo"<br/>";
       $val[] =$v;
     }
}
```

RESULT:

0---1
1---1
2---4
3---2
4---8
0---2
1---No items found
2---1
3---2
4---2

How to call individual items in the result above?
If I want to call say 'No items found'...How do I go about it?
 ORHow do I use implode to insert the values above into database.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO contract_item(group_item,item,kuantiti,harga,amount)VALUES ".implode(',', $val);
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
```

My ultimate goal is to insert the values carried by variable $v into table..ANy good approach is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if condition in the foreach loop will do the job as shown below

```
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{
    $firstRow = array_column($data, $i);
     foreach($firstRow as $k=>$v)
     {

       if ($v == "No items found")
       {
         echo 'No item has been used';
       }
       else
       {
        echo $k;//key
        echo"---";
        echo  $v;//value
        echo"<br/>";
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: not that I mean..how to address each individual value inside foreach? The 'No items found' is just an example

Comment: i see that you have edited your question, from your question you need to run the insert query inside the foreach block for each record individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{
    $firstRow = array_column($data, $i);
     foreach($firstRow as $k=>$v)
     {
        echo $k;//key
        echo"---";
        echo  $v;//value
        echo"<br/>";
       $val[$i][] =$v;
     }
}
```

And the result will be:

RESULT:

[0][0]---1

[0][1]---1

.....

.....

[1][0]---2

[1][1]---No items found

.....

.....